# I'm trying to create an off-center radial gradient background that doesn't wrap around

Tags: css, background, radial-gradients

I'm trying to make the `div` have a radial background where the white circle does not wrap around to the top of the `div`.

```
<div></div>

div {
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(300px, white 0%, #aab9c7 100%);
  background-position: top 200px left 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The gradient is first computed and drawn, then converted into a picture and behaves like any other background image.

Therefore, the default value `background-repeat: repeat;` is triggered, and the image is repeated:

```css
div {
  height: 400px; width: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(300px, white 0%, #aab9c7 100%);
  background-position: top 200px left 0;
}
div:hover {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me</div>
```

You are trying to manipulate the finished gradient instead of initially rendering it correctly.

It will be correct to specify the necessary values **​​directly in** the gradient properties: shape, position, sizes and colors.

```css
div {
  height: 400px; width: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(300px, white 0%, #aab9c7 100%);
}
div:hover {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at 50% 100%, white 0%, #aab9c7 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me</div>
```